Ag Grid: Disable autoResizeColumns for agGroupCellRenderer component
I am working with AgGrid and require the use of the agGroupCellRenderer, but I want to disable the auto-resizing of the columns. The auto-resizing is causing the grid to flicker when the row data in the group is updated and the columns are resized.
Tried adding the 'suppressSizeToFit' in the column definitions and 'suppressAutoSize' to the grid props, but it still does not disable the auto-resizing.
Anyone has any solution to stop this?
